# Web application requiring admin consent during token retrieval

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

My goal is to bypass the login screen and use Azure AD as the Identity Provider.

Given I am already logged in with my Azure AD user, I'd like to retrieve the authorization token using the silent flow and use this for resources that are protected.

I have a web application running on ASP.NET MVC 5 and a user-managed and backed by Azure AD (i.e. federated user). As a starting point, I have followed the steps in this article: [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Integrated-Windows-Authentication).

If I understand correctly, I should be able to use silent authentication since my users are federated and my application is registered as a public application.

In Azure AD, my app is registered with the following properties:

[image: id and access tokens]

[image: Public application]

[image: Permissions]

The code is straightforward, from the url.

```
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(
        new PublicClientApplicationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "<clientId>",
            TenantId = "<tenantId>",
            LogLevel = LogLevel.Verbose,
            AzureCloudInstance = AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic,
        })
    .Build();

var scopes = new [] { "User.Read" };

var result = await app.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(scopes)
    .WithUsername("<username>")
    .ExecuteAsync();
```

The call for acquiring the token throws the following exception:

> "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'xxx' named 'xxx'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource"

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference), `User.Read` doesn't need Admin Consent. 
So what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
I have constructed a URL that prompts for user consent: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/authorize?client_id=clientId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<myApp>&nonce=1234&resource=User.Read&prompt=consent`

It takes me to the screen where I need to pick my account, and after that, I get redirected to my app, where I get the same exception again.

So it doesn't show any consent screen, just asking me to pick the Microsoft account I want to use. Is this because of consent for `User.Read` is already granted by the admin?

But why am I still receiving the error? I'm a bit confused at this point.

Comment: Has a user or admin consented to the required permissions?

Comment: Are you looking to have the users sign in to your web app with their (federated) Azure AD user accounts? Or are you looking to get an access token on behalf of a user who has already signed in to the web app using Integrated Windows Auth?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret I am trying to sign in to my web app by using the federated Azure AD account, since I am already logged in with this account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing two different AAD OAuth mechanisms (aka v1 and v2 endpoints). The v1 endpoint uses Resources (`https://graph.microsoft.com`) while the v2 endpoint use Scopes (`user.read`). So when you request `resource=User.Read`, you are passing it an invalid resource name.

I would recommend using the v2 endpoint with the following URI prototype (line breaks for readability):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id={clientId}
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri={your_app}
&response_mode=fragment
&scope=user.read
```

Comment: Hi Marc. When using this url, it redirects me to the Microsoft login screen of my organisation, I then login in, I get redirected to my app's url that now has a code query string parameter filled in `url\?code=xxxxxx`.
My website has windows authentication turned on, however the call to `AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth` keeps throwing the same exception, saying I need user consent. Any idea which other setting is needed for this to work for a web app?

Comment: Could you try decoding that token you got back at https://jwt.ms? Make sure it includes the right tenant and scope.

Comment: You could also try swapping out `/common/` for `/{tenant id}/`. The last time I tried this, I believe I was always redirecting the user to the auth page using the tenant id. The first time it asked for consent but from that point forward it would just automatically redirect back. That said, this was a couple of years back so I may have forgotton a step.

Comment: Hi Marc, I did change it to `tenant_id` as I only want to allow accounts from my organisation to be able to login. Everything checks out, I can now move on to a different part of the flow. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Because Integrated Windows Authentication is a silent flow, the **user of your application must have previously consented to use the application** or the tenant **admin must have previously consented to all users** in the tenant to use the application.

You can force [user consent](http://prompt=consent) through a URL request with `prompt=consent`, the url will look like:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<client id>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<Your-Redirect-URI-Https-Encoded>&nonce=1234&resource=<your-resource-Https-encoded>&prompt=consent
```

If it needs [admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent#grant-admin-consent-through-a-url-request), use `$prompt=admin_consent` instead.(need to use admin account to sign in)

For more details about fix error AADSTS65001, you could refer to this [article](https://www.koskila.net/how-to-fix-admin-consent-issues-aadsts65001/).

Comment: I have tried to force user consent. The screen where I can pick a Microsoft account is displayed, after that I get redirected to my my website with no change in the behavior of `AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth()`.
I would expect to see the screen with the consent, but this is not the case. Any ideas?

Comment: Change the `resource=User.Read` to `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com` and try again.

Comment: By changing to `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com` I do get the popup, but after clicking Accept, the call to `AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth` still throws an exception asking for user consent.

Comment: If you are using .NET core or don't want to do an `AcquireTokenInteractive`, you might want to suggest the user to navigate `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&scope=user.read`. Refer to the `catch` in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token?tabs=dotnet#how-to-use-it).

Comment: `AcquireTokenInteractive` does not work in a web application as far as I can see. 
I receive this error and a web app as far as I know does not have a UI thread, which is what this method requires. Error is `ActiveX control cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment mvc controller`.

The whole idea was to be able to acquire the user/credentials silently since I'm already logged in, but it seems this doesn't work in an web app?

Answer (score -2):

With delegated permissions, **every** user will need to consent to the application. If you do not want that requirement, a tenant administrator can consent for all users from the Azure Portal.